# Swing application won't run on macOS

Tags: java, swing

My application works perfectly fine on my Windows machine, but when switching to macOS I get a null ptr exception every time I run the program. The constructor code isn't even reached, so I'm not sure why this would be. The stack trace points me to the initialization of a JFrame field. I'm not sure if this is an idiosyncrasy of Swing or an issue with my code. My main:

```
public static void main(final String[] theArgs) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TetrisGUI();
            }
        });
    }
```

the trace

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:509)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:549)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:423)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:224)
    at view.TetrisGUI.<init>(TetrisGUI.java:70)
    at view.TetrisMain$1.run(TetrisMain.java:27)
```

TetrisGUI

```
public class TetrisGUI implements Observer {

    .
    .
    .

70  /** The main GUI component that encapsulates all subsidiary components. */
    private final JFrame myMainFrame = new JFrame("UW CSS 305 - Tetris");

    .
    .
    .

    /**
     * Initializes GUI components, begins game. 
     */
    public TetrisGUI() {
        myMainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myMainFrame.setPreferredSize(getPreferredDim());
        myMainFrame.setResizable(false);

        myUserBoard = new Board();
        myUserBoard.addObserver(this);
        myAutoStepTimer = new Timer(500, event -> {
            myUserBoard.step();
        });

        myMainFrame.add(buildControlPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        myMainFrame.add(myGraphicPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        addKeyListeners();
        myMainFrame.pack();
        myMainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Update:
After a bit more digging I have discovered that this issue was due to my external monitor. I found this [Github issue](https://github.com/oracle/visualvm/issues/84) relating to the problem. Seems to be an issue with Swing.